# Python 3.10 not installing using brew

Tags: python, homebrew, root

[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gX9D3.png)I'm using a Macbook Pro 2017 with MacOS Monterey (I don't have space to update).

I'm trying to install root and one of the dependencies is python and it freezes and won't let me do anything.

I tried also with brew install root and it still freezes, I don't know what to do. how can I see the progress of this installation (in case there's any)?

Comment: As you write you don't have space to update, then how can you have enough space to install stuff?

Comment: It seems you might not have enough free disk space to download the file.